# TCP Java Client BufferedReader.readline() not returning buffer from C++ TCP Server

Tags: java, android, c++, tcp, bufferedreader

I'm having a problem with communicating between a C++ TCP server example that I found online and a java android application that I just threw together to see how the two could communicate back and forth.

For the Android client I had originally tried the AsyncTask class, but I was running into the problem of the Android socket closing. That would then break the loop of my C++ server and cause the server program to end successfully. I instead used a thread that would keep the socket open for the purpose of sending as much data back and forth until the client is done.

In the Android client code below, if I get rid of all the code associated with the bufferedReader, then I can send as much string data to the server as I want as the socket stays alive. If I add it, like below, and attempt to use the readline() function, then the function fails and prints a fatal exception.

As for my question, for what reason would I not be able to use readline() to get data back from the C++ server? Is there anything glaringly obvious that I should do?

### Android Java Client

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        sockThread = new Thread(sockApp = new SocketApp(ip, port));
        sockThread.start();
    }

    public void send_text(View v) {
        message = e1.getText().toString();
        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(sockApp.s.getOutputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(sockApp.s.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        printWriter.write(message);
        printWriter.flush();
        String line;
        try {
            //bufferedReader.readline() and the stacktrace is printed
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null && line.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

All this android app does is send string data to my computer with the C++ server on it and print it out. The SocketApp class just creates a socket with ip and port inputs.

### C++ Server Receive/Send to Android Client

```
char buf[4096]
while (true) {
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
    //wait for client to send data
    //After java exception is thrown, recv prints its error statement below
    int bytesReceived = recv(clientsocket, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Error in recv " << endl;
        break;
    }

    //cout << bytesReceived << endl;

    if (bytesReceived == 0) {
        cout << "client disconnected" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
    // echo message back to client
    send(clientsocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
}
```

The while block of C++ socket code to receive string data and then send it back

Comment: OK, so you couted a newline, but you didn't send it...

Comment: That's what the send function does, right under it.